# Help with hiding and fading-in elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to hide the `<p class = "hide">` elements, then fade them in by clicking the `<li>` they are nested within...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p.hide").hide();
  $("li").click(function(){
    ("p.hide").fadein(1000);
   };
  );  
};
```

and the HTML

```
<ul>   
   <li>Security</li>
     <p class = "hide">Nulla pharetra facilisis ligula sed ultricies.</p>  
   <li>Scalability</li>
     <p class = "hide">Nulla pharetra facilisis ligula sed ultricies.</p>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something here? Again, I'm new to jQuery/js and appreciate any help!

Comment: can you paste your html code for this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some minor syntax issues in your JS:

- closing paren missing from `ready()` function call
- semi-colon following anon function which was passed to `click()`
- lowercase 'i' in `fadeIn()` call

In your HTML, the P elements should be inside the LI elements--as posted it's not valid markup.

Also, your click targets all `p.hide` elements instead of the one nested inside the clicked `li`.

For example. Assume:

```
<ul>   
    <li>
        Security
        <p class="hide">Nulla pharetra facilisis ligula sed ultricies.</p>  
    </li>
    <li>
        Scalability
        <p class="hide">Nulla pharetra facilisis ligula sed ultricies.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then use this JS:

```
$( function()
{
    $( 'p.hide' ).hide();
    $( 'li' ).click( function()
    {
        $( this ).find( 'p.hide' ).fadeIn( 1000 );
    } );  
} );
```

Here is a live example of your code adjusted to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/u22yk/1/

Comment: @JAAule that's some interesting whitespace / layout you have. Never seen that much whitespace.

Comment: @Raynos, yes, I like whitespace in my development code, and I use minifiers/compressors to send it to production. :)

Comment: @starsinmypockets - perhaps, I'm not sure. I'd have to see what your Drupal is actually outputting to the browser.

Comment: @JAAulde - I've added your code from jsfiddle. A link to a working example is fine, but the code should be included here, if SO is going to be useful long-term.

Comment: @lwburk Since I have a JSFiddle account, that's a permanent posting. But I have no issue with you adding it here. I probably won't add it to my habits, though, as JSFiddle is where I post code.

Comment: @JAAulde - That makes no sense. You're just spreading your answer across two sites. Your answer shouldn't be a scavenger hunt.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that you will fade in *all* of the `'p.hide'` elements, not just the one within the `<li>`.

Try this small modification, you need to look at the children of the element in question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p.hide").hide();
  $("li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("p.hide").fadeIn(1000);
   };
  );
};
```